# Updating HTC Sensation to Ice Cream Sandwich is stuck in a boot loop

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rom-flashing, boot-loop, htc-sensation, stock-rom

I'm trying to update my unbranded HTC Sensation to an Ice Cream Sandwich stock ROM (from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1529941)).

I've followed the various instructions where I install the ROM, then flash the phone with the HTC Sensation firmware from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1412618), which matches my phone's CID.

The phone is now stuck in a boot loop, but I can't find any help out there for why it's doing this. Could anyone suggest an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer quicker than I thought I would, it turns out I was using the wrong firmware version. You need to check the ROM that the firmware is for, and apply it after the ROM is installed.

So my ROM is **Sensation_3.32.401.5_deodexed**

Which meant I should've chosen (from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1412618)):

> Firmware from 3.32.401.x & 3.32.401.10x RUU
>   --- MD5 checksum: 74A8E07D40A42DA1B4B56C224C42E692 *PG58IMG.zip ---
>   --- **Only for 3.32.401.x & 3.32.401.10x based ROMs**

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your CID to "Super CID" in this case you can install any ROM which is for an HTC-Sensation.

Open a new CMD/Terminal, navigate to your **abd & fastboot** folder and type:

```
adb reboot-bootloader
// wait until the phone reboots into fastboot mode
// check if the device is online
fastboot devices -l
// write the Super CID
fastboot oem writecid 11111111
```

This will write the "Super CID" (11111111) to your phone.
(Don't forget to save your old cid with `fastboot oem readcid`)

Hope this helps someone.