# HTC Sensation stuck in boot loop. Any possible fixes?

Tags: boot-loop, htc-sensation

Recently my HTC Sensation got stuck in a boot loop. I've tried factory reset and recovery to no avail. Upon getting to the screen, I get the following:

> PYRAMID PVT SHIP S-ON RL
>
> HBOOT-1.27.0000
>
> eMMC-boot
>
> HBOOT
>
> PG58DIAG.zip ...No image
>
> PG58IAG.nbh ... No image or wrong image
>
> PG58IMG.zip ... No image
>
> PG58IMG.nbh ... No image or wrong image
>
> PG58IMG.tar ... No image
>
> PG58IMG.aes

Any advise on possible fixes would be much appreciated as my phone is no longer under warranty and the alternative is giving my carrier more money. Whilst I am a complete n00b to it, I would not be unwilling to root the device if it could solve my problem (if it's even possible at this stage).

Cheers.

Comment: Did the boot-loop come out-of-the-blue, or was there something "special" you did before? Where you trying to flash something?

Comment: Boot-loop came completely without warning. I was trying to use google maps and got a message that my phone couldn't connect. Thinking nothing of it, I decided to reboot the phone and that's when the loop began.

Comment: Very strange. The listing you included with your question seems to indicate your device is looking for/at several image files (probably located on your SDCard?). PG58DIAG is a tool used e.g. [to unlock your device](http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/04/06/unlock-htc-sensation-with-pg58diag-easily/). Similar messages are [discussed at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1548260), and again [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1802359) (check the last link first).

Comment: PS: Doing a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22htc+sensation%22+pg58img.zip+%22No+image+or+wrong+image%22) suggests a failed (ICS?) update. Did you have an OTA notice you approved, so it might have tried to start the update in the background?

Comment: Not that I can recall re: the OTA notification. As I've said, I haven't made any attempt to unlock my device as I felt it was beyond my ability and most likely to brick it. At this stage, Three has wiped their hands clean and told me to either upgrade early or GTFO. As such, whilst I still feel I may screw it up, I've got nothing to lose. Would it be possible for me to recovery any functionality at this point?

Comment: Hard to say. You can at least backup the data from your SDCard. As you already have factory-reset the device, nothing to gain there. With nothing to lose, you could follow above links, unlock your device, and flash a new ROM unto it. As "the screen" lists you a bunch of files (most likely from your SDCard), you could also first try to boot it without any card (SD or SIM) in it. See also: [Updating HTC Sensation to Ice Cream Sandwich is stuck in a boot loop](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22343/16575) for a manual update to ICS.

Comment: I have the same prob only I bought mine from an older guy and it wasnt updated and was pretty much like no one touched it. I updated it, it took AGES and now it's in boot loop. Tried factory reset, tried recovery - you name it. Booted with no sim, booted with no sd, done it all. If anyone could help with clear instructions that would be great because I am in the same situation, not under waranty and I have no spare cash to take it to a 3rd party. I hear there is something you can do to the SD card re something to be loaded on to it (to help with answering the question) but I am not sure what i